# What to do with the "favorite code golf" question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

[The question in question.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/465/3808)

What should we do with it? It's clearly not a "proper" question for the Stack Exchange network (highly opinion-based and a "big list"), but it's CW and nobody's had a problem with it so far.

We could...

- Close it (primarily opinion based, too broad, etc.)
- Delete it (possible, but not necessary)
- Put a historical lock on it (the small amount of content there probably isn't worth a lock at this point)
- Leave it as is (probably not the best idea, since people will think these discussion forum-y type questions are perfectly fine)

Comment: It needs to be cleaned up for sure. I had hoped it would help preserve the best code-golf questions from stackoverflow before they were deleted. Seems they have all been deleted now, so people under 10k rep can no longer appreciate them.

Comment: I gave it some thought and I've deleted it now. I think I'll try to dig through the old questions on SO and reask some of the good ones here, since it's a large new audience.

Comment: Tagged [status-completed] so this stops showing up as a "hot meta post" in the sidebar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Close it.  It's clearly opinion-based and out of scope for this site, as per the help center.

"Best-of" lists might work better on a blog.

---

I understand that this question was asked back in the wild-west days of PPCG, but I think these days, the community has created/converged upon a much clearer idea of what this site is about.  This is a historical artifact, and I do believe in the preservation of historical artifacts if there are important things to be learned from them, but I don't think there's a whole lot to learned from this question.

Comment: You've been beating this drum all over the place. Have you read any of my comments to understand the intent? Can you suggest how to change it in a way that can preserve the history of stackexchange code golf?

Comment: @gnibbler Yes, sorry about that - I didn't think this was getting enough attention either, though for different reasons ;-)  I'll leave my drum alone now.  My only suggestion is to move this to a blog.  I'll be watching what the community does with great interest :)

Comment: I'm just a bit annoyed that they all got deleted. I asked for them to be migrated a couple of times, but apparently they can't because they are too old.

Comment: @gnibbler Yes, I agree that's shame.  If those old deleted code-golf questions are still visible to SO high-rep users, I for one would support their migration here, even as CW, if there are no duplication issues, perhaps under a historical tag or something.  If they are good, original questions, I think the PPCG community has grown enough that we could see some great new answers.

Comment: @gnibbler: According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152597/how-to-migrate-old-questions-to-a-new-graduated-site), we could build a list of *all* SO we want to receive and request the devs to migrate them.

Comment: @Dennis, Thanks for finding that!